# How does one model a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following problem:

A city has a population of 1 000 000 people. The population increases by 1 percent each year. Furthermore, every year there are 1 000 people moving to the city.

Now, if one is to create a function describing the population, initially if would be $f(0) = 1 000 000$. Seeing as it increases by 1 000 every year, the function should be $f(x) = 1 000 000 + 1 000x$. Also, there is another function that describes the increase in the population: because it is a differential equation, should that be the derivative of $f$? Intuitively is seems the function should be something like $x \mapsto 0.01x$, where $x$ is $f(x)$. Also, if function $f$ is specified as mentioned above, its derivative could not be $f'(x)=0.01x$

$y'+ay=0$

This is the form it should be written on, right?

How should one should approach these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially the population is $y_0$. At the end of year $i$ it is
$$y_i=y_{i-1}+a\,y_{i-1}+b$$ where $a$ is the percentage increase ($a=1\%$), and $b$ is the number of people that moved in. The equation can be rearranged to be
$$
y_i-y_{i-1}=a\,y_{i-1}+b\,.
$$
In the next round we use smaller time steps $\Delta t$ betweeen $t_{i-1}$ and $t_i$. To keep the the increases by $a$ and $b$ consistent it is reasonable to assume
that between those time steps the percentage increase is only $\Delta t\,a$ and the
people that move in are only $\Delta t\,b$. This gives
$$
y_i-y_{i-1}=\Delta t\,a\,y_{i-1}+\Delta t\, b\,.
$$
Dividing by $\Delta t$ and taking the limit leads to the ODE
$$
y'=a\,y+b\,.
$$

Comment: @DeltaFoxtrot Was this answer helpful ?